# Navigation bar affecting iframe ad placed on image

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have an iframe containing an image ad: [image]

I am having problems with a site which has a moving nav bar whose `position` changes from `inherit` to `fixed` at top.  It is affecting the `iframe` I have placed on the image on that page.

The `iframe` style is `position: absolute; overflow:hidden;`.

Comment: Can you be more specific about *how* the navbar is affecting your iframe?  What is the problem exactly?

Comment: @Daniel Beck:- My iframe is moving up and down on scroll. I mean when i scroll down the navbar is fixed and my iframe is pushed down. When i scroll up the navbar disappears so iframe goes up. generally the iframe fixes at bottom of image but this site is giving problem.